# Google Maps Custom Marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am inserting a custom marker in Google Maps and its not pointing accurately on the map. I Think its mainly because of the design of the pointing edge of the marker.

Is there any guide on how to make a custom marker ?

i am using the following lib: http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/

[image]

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 13.00487,
        lng: 77.576729,
        zoom: 13,
    });

    map.addControl({
        position: 'top_right',
        text: 'Geolocate',
        style: {
            margin: '5px',
            padding: '1px 6px',
            border: 'solid 1px #717B87',
            background: '#fff'
        },
        events: {
            click: function () {
                GMaps.geolocate({
                    success: function (position) {
                        map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('Geolocation failed: ' + error.message);
                    },
                    not_supported: function () {
                        alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    map.addMarker({
        lat: 13.00487,
        lng: 77.576729,
        title: 'Lima',
        icon: "http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png",
        infoWindow: {
            content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you probably want is something like this:

```js
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://i.imgur.com/3YJ8z.png',
    new google.maps.Size(19,25),    // size of the image
    new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin, in this case top-left corner
    new google.maps.Point(9, 25)    // anchor, i.e. the point half-way along the bottom of the image
);

map.addMarker({
    lat: 13.00487,
    lng: 77.576729,
    title: 'Lima',
    icon: image,
    infoWindow: {
        content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
    }
});
```

Comment: i am using the following lib. http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/ does it still hold good ?

Comment: yeah I think so, at a cursory look it just seems to pass the options straight through to the 'new google.maps.Marker()' function

Comment: PS: the `google.maps.MarkerImage` class is deprecated since I wrote this answer, and  you should use an [Icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) instead

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there are two basic ways to create a custom marker for Google Maps (API V3). The first is to use a "Custom Overlay", the second is to use a "Complex Icon". Both are explained in the official [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). You can..

1.) use a ["Custom Overlay"](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html?hl=en#CustomOverlays) if you want to display HTML

The Google Map documentation example "[Custom Overlays](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html)" shows how to create an own CustomMarker class based on the Google Maps OverlayView class

```
CustomMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CustomMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
  ..
}
overlay = new CustomMarker(..)
overlay.setMap(map);
```

2.) use a ["Complex Icon"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#ComplexIcons) if you want to display an image

The Google Map documentation example "[Complex Icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)" shows
   how to create a Google Marker with a complex icon, i.e. 
   an icon, a shadow image and a shape (the shape define the 
   clickable region of the icon)

```
 var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/flag.png', ..
 var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/shadow.png', ..
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: .., map: .., shadow: .., icon: image, shape: ..
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons and the syntax is explained at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage

In particular, where a custom marker is a different shape to a normal Google marker, the `anchor` parameter needs to be set correctly.

#### Following edit,

It appears that indeed you are using a small image, but everything is being treated as a normal-size Google marker. You need to make a custom marker (see above).